# How to execute javascript supplied by a text field

Tags: javascript

I am working on extending our companies analytics web application by adding the ability to do fully custom queries. As part of that, I have added a text field to the UI where a user will be able to type javascript. I am then looking to have the application take that javascript that was typed into the text field, execute it, and store the result into a variable.

In HTML, I have this:

```
<div class="div1">
   <div class="div1-1">
      <textarea name="customquery" id="customQuery" placeholder="Javascript function body where one can define a query script." />
   </div>
</div>
```

In my javascript file, I am looking for something that will allow me to do this:

```
var result = /* result of executing java script from the 'customquery' textarea*/
```

This will be part of a large javascript function that is triggered when the user clicks the 'submit' button on the web application.

How can I do this?

Comment: The best you're going to get is `eval`. If you literally just want to execute it from the user input. You should set the JS executor on another domain so it can't take control of your page. like SO does

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) does, but I'm also pretty sure you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you are looking for the [`eval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)-function. It takes a string, executes it as Javascript and returns the result if there is any.

I assume that you are aware of possible consequences for usability and security.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval(contents_of_textarea)` but eval is generally considered to be a Very Bad Thing, and you need to make sure people don't enter Bad Code That Could Cause Problems